# How to link to other websites in django?

Tags: python, html, django, hyperlink

I want to link my buttons to different websites in django website.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style='margin-left:15px'>
        <p><a href="#" target="blank">Contact</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">LinkedIn</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Twitter</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Google+</a></p>
    </div>
```

The above ***href*** only holds for the urls.py or only to the local pages of the project.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, your question is not clear at all

Comment: That is not true. You can open urls other than from your urls.py. Show the original code that you are trying. We cannot guess problem with `href="#"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve this :

```
<div class="container-fluid" style='margin-left:15px'>
            <p>
               <a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a> | 
               <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a> | 
               <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank">Twitter</a> | 
               <a href="https://plus.google.com" target="_blank">Google+</a>
            </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process_request)to detect the access to the other site and set [request.urlconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.urlconf) to the other urlconf that you want to use